# how to create .rSt files in django sphinx?

Tags: python, django, django-sphinx

```
.. Documentation_hexnode documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Mon May 09 14:24:54 2016.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.


Frequently Asked Questions
=================================================

Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
    license
    help

Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

This is my `index.rst` file after creating this file i run make HTML to make build.But `index.html` file does not have subheading license and help. Do i need to manually create `license.rst` and `help.rst` in source directory? Does it automatically generate while building?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create both `license.rst` and `help.rst`.

You can read more about toctree in [Sphinx documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/toctree.html#directive-toctree):